# Problems to install pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am having problems to install pyautogui. I have installed Python, Pip and Anaconda in my notebook, but when I try to install pyautogui using the code within cmd: pip install pyautogui I have the return bellow:

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/pyautogui/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyautogui/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyautogui/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyautogui (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyautogui

Someone could help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your setup, but here are a few things that might help:

- Generally, when you're installing a package, you go to the command prompt and type something like `python -m pip install pyautogui`; `python` is written here to tell the command prompt you're using the python language, `-m` tells it to look for a module (in this case pip) rather than some script file name, and `pip install pyautogui` means you're trying to install a module called pyautogui
- Pip looks in a few specific places for modules. If it doesn't find them there, it lets you know they were not found. If the module you're trying to install can't be found, generally you'll want to hunt down an actual file for it and install it with that file. However, I know it can find pyautogui, because I just installed it yesterday!
- If you're using a Jupyter Notebook within Anaconda, which it sounds like you are, you may not actually want to use your computer's command prompt. Your computer may be finding a different version of Python than your Anaconda installation. So, if you want to be able to use pyautogui in Anaconda, you'll want to follow these steps:

  1. Open Anaconda Navigator
  2. Launch the CMD.exe prompt in the Navigator, which is set up to deal with the Anaconda installation
  3. Type `pip install pyautogui` in this window and hit enter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but i had the same problem while creating a discord bot with discord.py , what i ended doing was downloading an SSL certificate from a website( search on google there are a bunch of them) then opening the download and it automatically sets it up. And that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command
`pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pyautogui`

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
py -m pip install pyautogui
```

Comment: Why? What result could that experiment yield? If it is meant as a solution, how does it work? Why does it help?

Comment: From OPs error, we can see the error is SSL certificate related, simply telling python that it needs to use the package pip, doesn't help.

Comment: I'm assuming that sometimes python is installed as 'py', but I'm not sure. If anybody has any ideas, please let me know.